# How to get the date of the albums,artists in android?

Tags: java, android, metadata, android-music-player

I want to list the recently added songs,albums and artists on my application.

I can able to get the date of song by using this code.

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED))
```

May I know how to get the **DATE ADDED** of **album** and **artist** ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the *MediaMetadataRetriever* can be of help here. With `String  extractMetadata(int keyCode)` you can retrieve Metadata from a media file. For your application the keyCodes `METADATA_KEY_DATE` or `METADATA_KEY_YEAR` might be interesting.

`METADATA_KEY_DATE` gives you the time and date the file was last modified.

`METADATA_KEY_YEAR` gives the year the file was originally created (if this Information was added by the creator and not mdified by someone else)

You can find more Details here:
[Adroid MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html)